# Gelfand triples/Rigged Hilbert space notation

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, distribution-theory

Usually the rigged Hilbert space is denoted by $\mathcal{S} \subset L^2 \subset \mathcal{S}'$, where $L^2$ is a Hilbert space (square integrable functions), $\mathcal{S}$ is the Schwartz space and $\mathcal{S}'$ the space of tempered distributions.

It's clear to me that $\mathcal{S}$ is a subset of $L^2$, but why do we write $L^2 \subset \mathcal{S}'$? These two sets have different elements. How is one subset of the other? One has functions and the other has functionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an abuse of notation.  It is true that, as you've stated, $L^2$ is not a subset of $\mathcal S'$.  What the notation $L^2\subset \mathcal S$ means is that $L^2$ embeds in $\mathcal S'$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please introduce a book or something where the concept of "embedding" is explained?

Comment: I just mean that there is a continuous injective linear map $L^2\to\mathcal S'$.  This is just the dual of the inclusion map $i:\mathcal S\to L^2$ (plus doing some stuff to take care of the fact that $(L^2)^*=L^2$ with conjugate scalar multiplication).

Comment: Thanks. When people say $\mathcal{H}^*=\mathcal{H}$ (Hilbert space is equal to its dual), is it also and abuse of notation? Do they mean there is a bijection between the two? Since again the objects in the two sets are different.

Comment: It's sort of an abuse of notation, sort of incorrect.  The map $\mathcal H\to\mathcal H^*$ given by $x\mapsto(y\mapsto\langle y,x\rangle)$ is an isometric anti-isomorphism (meaning that it is conjugate-linear).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that $\mathcal S$ is not a subset of $L^2$. Indeed, $L^2$ is not a set of functions but of equivalence classes of functions. Rigorously speaking, $\mathcal S \subset L^2$ is also an embedding.

Comment: @Héhéhé That's absolutely correct, thanks for clarifying.